# Using R to grab Windows AD userid

Tags: windows, r, rcurl

Does anyone know if it's possible to use R to grab the Windows AD userid and password?

I'm using RCurl to grab data from a BusinessObjects Web Service. Everything works fine except I have to pass my userid and password as parameters. Rather than hard coding my password into the code (as it will be used by others), I'd like to grab the AD userid and password and pass those with the HTTP request.

Any advice would be gratefully recieved.

Comment: Programmatically getting the clear-text password from the logged-in user? [Not even Windows lets you do that. :)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113592/getting-user-name-password-of-the-logged-in-user-in-windows)

Comment: No that's not what I meant. I think the correct terminology is Integrated Windows Authentication. Where Active Directory aware applications automatically authenticate connections.

According to good old Wikipedia: "Integrated Windows Authentication uses the security features of Windows clients and servers. Unlike Basic or Digest authentication, initially, it does not prompt users for a user name and password. The current Windows user information on the client computer is supplied by the web browser...". So I want to know is there a way of doing this with R?