# C# Winform login using windows'user

Tags: c#, authentication, ldap, windows-authentication

Can I Login A winform using windows user login information. I need password to login my system but I can't get user's password. Is there any thing like password from windows's user to login.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting user name/password of the logged in user in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113592/getting-user-name-password-of-the-logged-in-user-in-windows)

Comment: I recommend using OokiiDialog's credentials dialog. http://www.ookii.org/ Alternatively, you could roll with your own credentials dialog.

Comment: @shf301 I don't think the answer there is the one he is seeking for. He's not asking for an API, because he most likely knows that there isn't one.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using [Ookii's Ookii.Dialogs](http://www.ookii.org/Software/Dialogs/), which provides a library where you can use a sleek prompt to get the user's password if required for any authentication tasks you wish to process.

Note: after adding a reference to their library, you must include this line along the top lines:

> using Ookii.Dialogs;

Here is an example code snippet on how to properly utilize it:

```
string strUsername = "";
string strPassword = "";

CredentialDialog crDiag = new CredentialDialog();
crDiag.Content = "Your email will be sent using your following credentials.";
crDiag.MainInstruction = "Please enter your email address and password";
crDiag.Target = "MyProgram";

if (crDiag.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    strUsername = crDiag.UserName;
    strPassword = crDiag.Password;
    //Do whatever you want to do here, if they provided a username and password
}

//Do whatever you want to do here, regardless of whether they did provide or didn't
```

Below is a screenshot of how the dialog will appear when you call ShowDialog():

The username field can accept things other than email addresses as well. It just depends on what you want to do with it.

[image]

Comment: give error on DialogResult.OK, does not exist in current context

Comment: @Harshal You may have to tweak some things then, their library isn't that easy to use to be honest, and requires experimentation to get the fully desired result. I did not have that error myself though however.

Comment: error get resolve by adding System.Windows.Forms refrence

Comment: @Harshal You weren't using a WinForm project at the very start to test/use it?